# If it is possible to make games without coding, why code one?

Tags: game-engine

I'm pretty new to coding and while searching on random stuff on the internet i found out that it is possible to make games without a single line of code with the help of game-engines like Unity. So what merit is there in coding a game? I have my guesses but i would like to have an answer to be sure, thank you in advance.

Comment: Using a game engine doesn't implies absolute no code. It just does a few things out of box, but the main logic, graphics and the like are yours to make, using code.

Comment: I think Unity engine has a backend code, that is complex to newbies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unity requires coding for anything truly custom**

You can get quite far with Unity just using already built stuff, but that's just the problem. You are limited to using the parts someone has already made and combining them. Now, that does allow for a heck of a lot of combinations but that is as far as you can go.

You are also limited in your ability to correct unwanted behavior in precisely the way you want it to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn coding in order to make games and that includes using gaming engines such as Unreal or Unity engines. The main reason on why you would need to learn coding is to add logic to your game such as moving your character.

If you are using Unity I would suggest referring to the following link and learn more about scripting(aka coding) and how can you implement it in your game and that way you would have a better idea on why/when coding is essential to the game you're creating.

https://learn.unity.com/project/beginner-gameplay-scripting?courseId=5c61706dedbc2a324a9b022d